# jQuery UI sortable images

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I ‘d like some help please, as my skills in jQuery are not so good. What I want to achieve is to change the order of the images like [this](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) example.

My database looks like this:

```
table: Gallery
img_id (pk)
image
caption
order
```

I have also created these 2 views:
**index.php**

```
<!-- will display the ajax result -->
<div id="orderResult"></div>
<hr/>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-primary">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/galleries/order_ajax'); ?>', {}, function(data) {
            $('#orderResult').html(data);
        });

        // save order
       $('#save').click();
    });
</script>
```

**order_ajax.php**

```
<?php if(count($images)>0): ?>
<div class="sortable-list">
    <ol id="sortable">
        <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <li <?php echo 'id="li_'.html_escape($image->img_id).'"'; ?>><?php echo img(array('src' => 'uploads/thumbs/'.html_escape($image->image)); ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>  
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
         $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

I have also created and the order_ajax controller

```
public function order_ajax(){
 // save order from pages
 var_dump($_POST);

  // if (isset($_POST['sortable'])) {
  // $this->gallery->save_order($_POST['sortable']);
  // }

 // fetch all images (fetch all data)
 $this->data['images'] = $this->gallery->get();

 // load the view
 $this->load->view('admin/gallery/order_ajax', $this->data, false);
}
```

So what I basically want to do is to drag the images around in order to change their order, and when I click the save button pass the (new) data/order to the controller and to store them in the database. How can I make this work?

Comment: You send JSON via AJAX to PHP file (controller+method) and save the order to database. I have no clue what kind of data does sortable plugin give back.

Comment: I did an update, please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was more simple than I thought.

On the index.php view I've put this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('admin/galleries/order_ajax'); ?>", {}, function(data) {
            $('#orderResult').html(data);
        });

        // save order
        $('#save').click(function(){
            var new_order = $("#sortable").sortable( "toArray" );

            $.post("<?php echo site_url('admin/galleries/order_ajax'); ?>", { order_array: new_order }, function(data) {
                    $('#orderResult').html(data);
                });
        });  
    });
</script>
```

and this is the controller function

```
public function order_ajax(){
    // save order from pages
    if (isset($_POST['order_array'])) {
        $this->gallery_model->save_order($_POST['order_array']);
    }

    // fetch all images
    $this->data['images'] = $this->gallery->get();

    // load the view
    $this->load->view('admin/gallery/order_ajax', $this->data, false);
}
```